# Keyboard shortcut for Show All Files

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Has anyone found a keyboard shortcut for the "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer ?

And a related question ... is there any tool that can show the keyboard shortcut for any operation you're doing in VS ?

Cheers,

SteveC.

Comment: I recommended creating a separate StackOverflow question for your related question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is none by default. But:

Go to Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard.

In 'Show commands containing", type:

> showall

Scrolling in the list of commands reveals: `Project.ShowAllFiles`.
Select it and type the shortcut you want in the "Press shortcut keys" edit box. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

If what you type as shortcut already has an associated command, you will see it in the bottom of this dialog.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2013, use `alt` + `p` + `o`.

Comment: Works in VS 2017 as well

Comment: Works in VS 2019 as well