# How can you stop a Winforms Panel from scrolling with Override a Class?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, panel

I'm dealing with an 'old' problem, the scroll position from a Panel is reset when returning to the application after leaving it.
I've got a DataGridView on a Panel, for the Panel the AutoScroll = True, so when the DataGridView is wider as the panel the horizontal scrollbar will appear.
When the user scrolls the Panel to a certain scroll position and leave the application, when returning to the application the scrollbar position is reset to the beginning.
I found several posts describing this behavior, one of the solutions that people talk about is: 'There is an overrideable ScrollToControl method in the ScrollableControl now. Replace the call to the base class implementation to return DisplayRectangle.Location and problem solved'
See: http://seewinapp.blogspot.com/2005/09/is-your-autoscroll-too-auto.html

I can not get to the right solution, how can I override the base class?
Can I override the base class when the panel is not placed programmatically?

I've already tried several things, almost tried every event to catch and set the scroll position to the value when the form is deactivated.

Please point me in the right direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's say you have created `MyPanel` class fixing the problem. To replace the existing panel which you have in `Form1`, open the `Form1.desiger.cs` and replace `Panel` with `MyPanel`.

Comment: Thanks Reza for you reaction. Could it be that I did not have a 'designer.cs' but only a 'designer.vb'?

Comment: That's the designer generated code for a Form1.vb

Comment: Ok, could you tell me where i can find the designer.cs? Btw, I'm in VB.net.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099743/3110834

Comment: The penny has dropped Reza, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!