# How to disable keyboard shortcut for Show all files

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

The `Show All Files` option in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer keeps toggling on for some reason. What shortcut key does it use and how do I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

For some time now I would randomly find the Show All Files option enabled in solution explorer and I couldn't figure out what was causing it. Thanks to [Keyboard shortcut for Show All Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674412/keyboard-shortcut-for-show-all-files) I knew the keys but there was no keyboard shortcut bound to the SolutionExplorer.Folders.ShowAllFiles command. What's actually happening is that `Alt+P` opens the Project menu then pressing `O` will toggle show all files.

[image]

This was happening often to me because I use Visual Assist's `Open File in Solution` default shortcut `Alt+Shift+O` and would sometimes hit `P` on the way accidentally. To remove this shortcut and behavior you actually need to edit your menu items. Open the Customize menu (Tools->Customize) and remove both entries for `Show All Files`.

[image]